# ViewData is empty when returning view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am completely baffled by this s I have never came across this. I have a shared view called "Error" which outputs a standard message followed by a custom message:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}

<h2>
    Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request. @{ ViewData["ErrorMessage"].ToString(); }
</h2>
```

Inside a controllers catch block I am setting the ViewData to the custom message:

```
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ...
        ViewData["ErrorMessage"] = "This is my custom message";
        return View("Error");
    }
```

However, when the view is loaded, the ViewData shows my key "ErrorMessage" but never outputs the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression does not display anything because you don't write out the `ViewData["ErrorMessage"]` to the response.

With the `@{ ... }` you create a razor code block which does not write anything to the output just executes the code what is inside.

To write to the output you need to use the `@` sign:

```
<h2>
    Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request. @ViewData["ErrorMessage"]
</h2>
```

More info about the [razor syntax.](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx)

Comment: That was it. Man, I am a simple sh**.